# How to limit selection in method paramters in Ruby using enums in this code?

Tags: ruby, enums, parameter-passing

I have this code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 #encoding: utf-8
 require "csv"

  class FileTypeEnum

  channel=0
  national=1
  regional=2
  end


  class CsvParser

 attr_accessor :row_hash, :file_path, :mode

    def initialize(filePath, file_type_enum) #Client should only pass the legal values of file_type_enum
 @file_path = filePath
 @mode = file_type_enum #mode should be one of the 3 legal integer values corresponding to the enum

 puts "CSV Parser received = #{filePath}"
 csv = CSV.read("#{filePath}")

     case @mode
 when 0
    parse_channel
 when 1
    parse_national
 when 2
    parse_regional
 else
    puts "Error in method invocation"
 end

    end#initialize
```

This is how I found from googling to make enums work in Ruby since there is no native enum class.

Here is what Im trying to accomplish

```
 1) any code that instantiates CsvParser must only be able to pass the legal values for the parameter "file_type_enum"

 2) Can someone give an example of code of How I can retrieve the integer value inside initialize from the enum parameter and set mode.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your enum isn't even valid for your purposes. They have to be constants, not variables. Try this:

```
class FileTypeEnum
  CHANNEL=0
  NATIONAL=1
  REGIONAL=2
end
```

The only way to do this is to check if the values are within a correct range. Something like this:

```
unless([0,1,2].includes? file_path_enum)
  raise ArgumentError.new("The file_path_enum argument must be one of the values defined by FileTypeEnum.")
end
```

However, using enums at all is not very Rubyish. Symbols are a much better alternative in Ruby, and far clearer when the value of the enum constant doesn't matter in and of itself.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would do this using symbols?

Comment: @rozza: Instead of defining a type (`FileTypeEnum`), you just decide on a couple of symbols to represent your options. For example, you could say that valid options for file_type are `:channel`, `:national`, and `:regional`. Is that clearer?

Comment: @rozza: To make sure only valid options are passed, just do something along the lines of `raise "Invalid option." unless [:channel, :national, :regional].include? file_type`.